# REST combined with inheritance in Web APIs

Tags: c#, rest, inheritance

We're currently designing some data services, which should deliver data to many individual parties and therefore be generic enough to be shared but not to complex to understand.
Generally, it's quite simple, some but we're not at the point, where we're discussing the possibilities for core data, which has some inheritance hierarchies as well as additional data.
For example:

- Individual ist just a Individual (no shaping)
- Individual is an Employee
- Individual is an Event Participant
- etc

Also, an Indivivual HAS additional data

- Addresses
- Phone numbers
- etc

Watching several REST best practices documents, for example https://pages.apigee.com/rs/apigee/images/api-design-ebook-2012-03.pdf, the closest to the solution I see is to create endpoints for each inherited Type:

- ServiceApi/DataServices/v1/Individuals
- ServiceApi/DataServices/v1/Employees

And probably add the "Has"-data with a partial response mechanism. This seems odd, since now the consumer has to know, what subtype he asks for.

Another solution could be to add a lot of endpoints and create a DTO for each requested possibility:

- IndividualWithAddresses
- IndividualWithPhoneNumbers
- EmployeeWithPhoneNumbers

None of these solutions, and neither the others we found, seems appealing. I feel like the big API providers, which surely have a way richer data model, must have had similar discussions. Is there a solution to keep the complexity in check and still stay flexible enough?

Comment: Why not have a single Individials endpoint that contains additional fields when relevant?

Comment: Could you give an example? One requirement is also, that people, who are interested in just Employees, should have a possibility to get just them. With one endpoint they would to fetch ALL individuals and filter in their side, if I understood you correctly?